# Hide all table rows except clicked row AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table that is populated with ng-repeat. When the row is clicked I am retrieving the data related to the object with ng-click.  The table is populated with a json file.  How can I hide all of the other rows of the table when the selected row is clicked?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody style="cursor: pointer" ng-cloak> <!--When the row is clicked, I want to hide all other rows except the clicked one.-->
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="getSelected(person);">
            <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    angular.module("App", []).controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.people = peopleData;
        $scope.getSelected = function (person) {
            $scope.selected = person;
        };
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `<tr>`.  It basically says, hide this row if there is a selection and that selection isn't the current person being iterated over.

```
ng-hide="selected && selected !== person"
```

Comment: If you need them to reappear just set 'selected' to null

Comment: Wow!  Thanks!  I was just trying to figure that out. I just started using Angular today.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You could just set an `ng-hide` value on unselected rows when a selected value has been set:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody style="cursor: pointer" ng-cloak ng-repeat="person in people"> <!--When the row is clicked, I want to hide all other rows except the clicked one.-->
        <tr ng-hide="selected!==null && person!==selected" ng-click="getSelected(person);">
            <td>{{ person.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    angular.module("App", []).controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.people = peopleData;
        $scope.selected = null;
        $scope.getSelected = function (person) {
            $scope.selected = person;
        };
    });
</script>
```

You will also probably want to move the `ng-repeat` as I did in the code above.